# CREATE EXTENSION silently fails in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a `pgvector` extension on my server programmatically though `sqlalchemy` but the execute instruction fails silently.

Here is the code:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{cfg.DB.USERNAME}:{cfg.DB.PASSWORD}@{cfg.DB.URL}/{cfg.DB.NAME}")
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute(text("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vector"))
```

This code doesn't raise an error, but the extension is not created.

I checked that connection is correct, since other SQL queries seem to work.

If I execute the same SQL through `psql` it successfully creates the extension.

The database is AWS Aurora Serverless V2 - PostgreSQL flavour.
`sqlalchemy==2.0.25`, `PostgreSQL 15.4 on aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

What can be the problem?

Comment: Take a look at the Postgres log to see if the error is shown there.

Comment: There is nothing in the error logs and I can't seem to find the option to view other ones.

Comment: `log_statement` is unset and I don't seem to have the option of changing it.

Comment: Are you sure `cfg.DB.URL` and `cfg.DB.NAME` are correct?

Comment: Yes, other commands work as expected.

Comment: At this point I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Did you turn on echo ? Do you need to commit?

Comment: If you turn on echo on engine you can see if rollback occurs.

Comment: Try without the `IF NOT EXISTS` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Running without `IF NOT EXISTS` doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I needed a commit.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, text
engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{cfg.DB.USERNAME}:{cfg.DB.PASSWORD}@{cfg.DB.URL}/{cfg.DB.NAME}")
with engine.connect() as con:
    con.execute(text("CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS vector"))
    con.commit() # <- This.
```